# TkTable insert rows python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scrollbar, tk-toolkit

Hi I am trying to create a table using Tktable and the wrapper i found online : http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/TkTableWrapper

I am having trouble understanding how to add rows. I have been modifying the sample_test method included in the file with no success.

My end goal is to have a table in my GUI and then write a row every time i read in data from a serial connection. I therefore would not know how many rows i will need. I could just pre-assign a very large table but this seems slow. I am expecting to read off a very large number of datapackets (potentially in the tens of thousands).

I have tried the insert_rows method but I don't think I fully understand how it works and the documentation is a bit sparse.

Also, I could not get the scroll bar to work. while i could add it easily by adding the lines below before the test.pack method call, they wouldn't scroll with the mouse. I think the binding is off:

```
scroll = Tkinter.Scrollbar(root)
test.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
scroll.pack(side=Tkinter.RIGHT,fill=Tkinter.Y)
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, sample_test creates a table with the configuration option
state='disabled' (this is why you can't add more rows).
Try setting it to state='normal', either at creation, or whenever you need
to make changes, whichever suits best.

```
def sample_test():
    from Tkinter import Tk, Scrollbar, Button

    def test_cmd(event):
        print 'command'

    def browsecmd(event):
        print 'browsecmd'
        #print event.__dict__

    root = Tk()
    quit = Button(root, text="QUIT", command=root.destroy)
    quit.pack(side = 'bottom')    

    numrows, numcols = 10, 10

    var = ArrayVar(root)
    for y in range(numrows):
        for x in range(numcols):
            index = "%i,%i" % (y, x)
            var[index] = index

    test = Table(root,
                 rows=numrows+1,
                 cols=numcols+1,
                 state='normal',
                 width=6,
                 height=6,
                 titlerows=1,
                 titlecols=1,
                 roworigin=-1,
                 colorigin=-1,
                 selectmode='extended',
                 selecttype='row',
                 rowstretch='unset',
                 colstretch='last',
                 browsecmd=browsecmd,
                 flashmode='on',
                 variable=var,
                 usecommand=0,
                 command=test_cmd)

    # http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm
    s = Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical', command=test.yview_scroll)
    test.config(yscrollcommand=s.set)
    s.pack(side='right', fill='y')

    test.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
    test.tag_configure('sel', background = 'yellow')
    test.tag_configure('active', background = 'blue')
    test.tag_configure('title', anchor='w', bg='red', relief='sunken')

    data = ('py','t','h','o','n','','+','','Tk','')

    def add_new_data(*args):
        #test.config(state='normal')
        test.insert_rows('end', 1)
        r = test.index('end').split(',')[0] #get row number <str>
        args = (r,) + args
        idx = r + ',-1'
        test.set('row', idx, *args)
        test.see(idx)
        #test.config(state='disabled')

    root.after(3000, add_new_data, *data)
    root.after(4000, add_new_data, *data)
    root.mainloop()
```